# Does memoir class have various page designs built in?

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I wasn't able to find an answer to this question myself - are there any built-in page designs (styles) in `memoir` class? If so, what are they and how do I set them in the document to see how each one of them looks?

Comment: See §6.5 of the `memoir` manual, which discusses chapter styles, and has examples.

Answer (score 20):

Section 7.2 *PAGE STYLES* of the `memoir` manual describes the pre-defined page styles:

> The page styles provided by the class
>   are:
>
> *empty* The headers and footers are empty.
>
> *plain* The header is empty and the folio (page number) is centered at the
>   bottom of the page.
>
> *headings* The footer is empty. The header contains the folio at the outer
>   side of the page; on verso pages the
>   chapter name, number and title, in
>   slanted uppercase is set at the spine
>   margin and on recto pages the section
>   number and uppercase title is set by
>   the spine margin.
>
> *myheadings* Like the headings style the footer is empty. You have to
>   specify what is to go in the headers.
>
> *simple* The footer is empty and the header contains the folio (page
>   number) at the outer side of the page.
>   It is like the headings style but
>   without any title texts.
>
> *ruled* The footer contains the folio at the outside. The header on verso
>   pages contains the chapter number and
>   title in small caps at the outside; on
>   recto pges the section title is
>   typeset at the outside using the
>   normal font. A line is drawn
>   underneath the header.
>
> *Ruled* This is like the ruled style except that the headers and footers
>   extend into the fore- edge margin.
>
> *companion* This is a copy of the pagestyle in the Companion series
>   (e.g., see [MG+ 04]). It is similar to
>   the Ruled style in that the header has
>   a rule which extends to the outer edge
>   of the marginal notes. The folios are
>   set in bold at the outer ends of the
>   header. The chapter title is set in a
>   bold font flushright in the verso
>   headers, and the section number and
>   title, again in bold, flushleft in the
>   recto headers. There are no footers.
>
> *book* This is the same as the plain pagestyle.
>
> *chapter* This is the same as the plain pagestyle.
>
> *cleared* This is the same as the empty pagestyle.
>
> *part* This is the same as the plain pagestyle.
>
> *title* This is the same as the plain pagestyle.
>
> *titlingpage* This is the same as the empty pagestyle.

EDIT: You can see them in action using this simple document

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{background}

\SetBgContents{empty}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\SetBgContents{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\SetBgContents{headings}
\pagestyle{headings}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\SetBgContents{simple}
\pagestyle{simple}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\SetBgContents{ruled}
\pagestyle{ruled}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\SetBgContents{Ruled}
\pagestyle{Ruled}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\SetBgContents{Companion}
\pagestyle{companion}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Each group of four pages illustrates one style (I didn't include the `myheadings` style); the `background` package was used to inform the corresponding style that is being used.